# Using modules imported from another import

Tags: python, python-3.x, import

I'm cleaning up a project that was refactored into smaller .py files. I noticed that a lot of modules are being imported again and again in various files. Some statements are in files that import another which has the same import statement used by the importing file. For example:

**main.py**

```
import alt
print (os.getcwd())
```

**alt.py**

```
import os
```

The `print(os.getcwd())` throws a `NameError: name 'os' is not defined`. Shouldn't `os` be part of `sys.modules` when the import statement is executed in alt.py?

Is it possible to use a module imported by another module that was imported first?

Comment: is import os working in python shell ? import sys is working ?

Comment: Which line throws the error?

Comment: @MichaelButscher see edit

Answer (score 9, accepted):

They are available in the following namespace:

```
import alt
print (alt.os.getcwd())
```

Comment: @datta what do you mean by "invoke the scope"?

Answer (score 4):

To answer your immediate question, it is possible but not recommended.

Imports adjust the namespace in which they are made. This means that `alt` has an attribute `os` that can be accessed in `main` as

```
print(alt.os.getcwd())
```

This is not the recommended way, however, since it makes it less clear which actual `os` module you are using. You should do `import os` directly in `main`. This will *not* create a separate module object, so do not worry about cluttering your memory with duplicate modules.

The first time an import is encountered during runtime, it is added to the dictionary `sys.modules`, keyed by the fully qualified name of the module. Future import statements will look in `sys.modules` for an existing reference before doing any actual work.

In your case, `import alt` will create a module referenced by `sys.modules['alt']` as well as by the name `alt` in `main`. The statement `import os` in `alt` will be run next. It will create a module referenced by `sys.modules['os']` and `alt.os`. If you were to add a line `import os` in `main` after `import alt`, it will not create and load another module object. Instead, the name `os` will be bound to the same object pointed to by `sys.modules['os']`.

The following three versions of `main` will all call the same `getcwd` function:

1. Direct import (recommended):

   ```
   import alt
   import os
   print(os.getcwd())
   ```
2. Use the reference in `alt` (harder to read/trace):

   ```
   import alt
   print(alt.os.getcwd())
   ```
3. Using `sys.modules` (really not recommended for production unless you know what you are doing):

   ```
   import alt  # necessary to trigger the actual import
   import sys
   print(sys.modules['os'].getcwd())
   ```

All imports load a full module. This even applies to imports of the form `from os import getcwd`. The module `sys.modules['os']` is still created. The only difference is that the importing namespace will only have access to the name `getcwd`, not `os`. In your case, if `alt` contained `from os import getcwd` instead of `import os`, the three access methods would change as follows:

1. Unchanged.
2. `print(alt.getcwd())` since `alt.os` no longer exists.
3. Unchanged.

Answer (score 1):

You are importing `os` only in the in the submodul level of `alt`. `os` is to say so only available by access through `alt.os`. A way around this would be to import all from alt as `from alt import *`, but this is not what you should do...

As a general rule of thumb, you should re-import your directly called-to modules on the top level of the module that you currently process.
thus at main.py:

```
 import os
```

and everything is fine

Comment: AFAIK you can't import using 'alt.py', but 'alt'.

Answer (score -1):

You write it this way

```
__author__ = 'kerberos'
__date__ = '2017/10/25 20:48 '
import alt
print(alt.os.getcwd())
```

This is the result:

C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\11